# Start iOS navigation out of safari

Tags: ios, navigation

is there a a way to open the maps app in iOS 6 with a hyperlink in safari?
I would like to give users the possibility to navigate by car to a destination from the current location. So this hyperlink would need the destination as one of the parameters.

Tanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This URL would open the iOS 6 maps app with directions from Cupertino to San Francisco.

http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino

For just a destination:

http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=10690+North+De+Anza+Boulevard,Cupertino,CA+95014

For reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html